# How to prevent React-tooltip from disappearing when moused over

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the [react-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip) library to create a tooltip over a button.

I want to be able to copy the text from the tooltip when opened, however the tooltip automatically closes when the mouse is moved from the button element. I only want the tooltip to close when the mouse is outside the button and tooltip element.

Heres a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tooltip-basic-example-forked-fmfxbk?file=/src/Row.js:180-639), I created to illustrate what I mean.

```
    <div>
      <button data-tip data-for='name-tooltip'>
        Register 
      </button>
      <ReactTooltip
        clickable
        id='name-tooltip'
        place="top"
        effect="solid"
      >
       <p>Test</p>
        <CopyToClipboard text="This is a test">
          <div>Test</div>
        </CopyToClipboard>
      </ReactTooltip>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess you could add a delayHide time to allow some time for the user to move their cursor to the overlay itself, and when that happens add a hover event to force keep it open. That said, it might not be intended to be used that way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really want to go that route unless necessary

Comment: Seems to be an open issue? https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/319

Comment: Also, if you need to conform to any accessibility guidelines, the delay time probably won't be a great workaround, depending on which level WCAG must  be met.